# How do I use web sockets in javascript/html5 to communicate with python

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, websocket

I'm having issue's with trying to communicate between python and javascript using WebSockets.

This is my python server (ws.py) which just prints out any data it receives and resends it to the client :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''   
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
   data = conn.recv(1024)
   if not data: break
   print 'Data recieved =', data
   conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

This works fine with netcat using `nc localhost 50007` but when I try using my html/Javascript client I get a connection but the server doesn't receive the message I just get the follow:

```
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 62264)
Data recieved = GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:50007
Origin: http://localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 6hxDWShxMnFxwGYAWym+eg==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
Cookie: SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2
```

and this is what I get the the console in Chrome:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:50007/' failed:  basicWSoc.html:7
Error Logged: [object Event]
```

This is my web client (basicWSoc.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function WebSocketTest()
  {
    var connection=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:50007");
    connection.onopen = function () {
      connection.send('Hello, Server!!'); //send a message to server once connection is opened.
    };
    connection.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('Error Logged: ' + error); //log errors
    };
    connection.onmessage = function (e) {
      console.log('Received From Server: ' + e.data); //log the received message
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sse">
   <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am still a novice in python and Web sockets are completely new to me so I may be over looking the obvious....

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Web Sockets is a specific protocol, not raw sockets.  You need a Python WebSocket server.

Comment: @sLaks would you have any recommendations to where I might find an example as basic as I have done? anywhere I have looked is very code heavy and I find it hard to understand . I don't mind using a library if thats what is needed I would just like my python script to be as straight forward as possible

Comment: @SLaks also am I still using a raw socket when I'm using `socket.SOCK_STREAM` ,I thought this uses TCP ?

Comment: Web Sockets is a protocol build on top of TCP.  You need to implement this protocol.

Comment: @SLaks Ok thanks, I've got it working using [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SLaks who pointed out to me that I was using TCP sockets as apposed to Web Sockets. I changed my Python service to use the [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) Library which implemented web sockets and this allowed me to connect to my web client and successfully communicate between them